# Comparing ArrayLists containing objects

Tags: object, arraylist

> I have two ArrayLists: A and B Both ArrayLists have a bunch of objects
>   stored inside. A has more than B. I am trying to store the objects
>   that are in A but not in B in a new ArrayList called C. Each object
>   has a few data members but I compare only two of them - "Name" and
>   "OtherName".
>
> > boolean found;
> >
> > ```
> >     for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
> >     {
> >         found = false;
> >         for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++)
> >         {   if (A.get(i).getName().equals(B.get(j).getName()) 
> >                   &&
> >             A.get(i).getOtherName().equals(B.get(j).getOtherName()))        
> >                     {
> >                    found = true;        
> >                     }
> >         }
> >         if (found = true)
> >             {
> >                 C.add(A.get(i));           
> >             }
> >     }
> > ```
>
> The issue is that ArrayList 'c' is being stored with ALL the objects
>   from a, instead of just with the ones that are in 'a' but not in 'b'.
>   What am I doing wrrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a simple mistake:

This line:

```
if (found = true)
        {
            C.add(A.get(i));           
        }
```

Needs to be:

```
if (found != true)
        {
            C.add(A.get(i));           
        }
```

You need to compare value of found to the value of true by using the not equals ("!=") sign. By using found = true. You are setting found to true every time the if statement is executed, instead of comparing the value.

That line can also be written as (They mean the same thing):

```
if (!found)
        {
            C.add(A.get(i));           
        }
```

Comment: Oh it is true. Silly mistake.
Changed it, but now for some reason it stores 'c' with JUST the objects from 'b'

Comment: Ah, I believe your logic is incorrect. You want: found != true. You want values to be inserted into C if they are not found. Am I correct? If you change that, it should fix your problem.

Comment: http://img.pandawhale.com/post-25367-give-that-man-a-cookie-meme-Pu-7nU9.jpeg

Awesome. Thanks!
How come I can't vote you up?

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Please upvote and accept the answer so that viewers see the problem was resolved, in case people run into the same problem.

Comment: Click the up arrow above the 0 that is to the left of the question. And press the checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: I was able to press the checkmark, but it doesn't let me vote up.
It says "Vote up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: Aha, you're new to the site. No worries. You have to have 15 rep before you can upvote so don't worry about it. Thanks!